# Powershell Where-Object CmdLet with -Cin option not giving the expected result

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter the items in a PSCustomobject with Where-Object CmdLet. At first I tried to filter the contents of the PSCustomobject Object with Where-Object CmdLet with -Ccontains option as show below...

```
 $a1 = [PSCustomObject]@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 1111)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 2222)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 3333)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 4444)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 1111)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 2222)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 3333)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 4444)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
)
$a1_filtered = $a1 | Where-Object -Property 'k1' -Ccontains -Value 'password'
Write-Host $a1_filtered
```

The above code worked and I am getting the expected result and is shown below...

```
@{k1=System.Object[]; k2=x} @{k1=System.Object[]; k2=x} @{k1=System.Object[]; k2=x} @{k1=System.Object[]; k2=x}
```

But when I tried to achieve the same result with Where-Object CmdLet with the -Cin option as shown in the following code, I am getting empty result.

```
$a1 = [PSCustomObject]@(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 1111)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 2222)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 3333)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('password', 4444)
        k2 = 'x'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 1111)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 2222)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 3333)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        k1 = @('username', 4444)
        k2 = 'y'
    }
)
$a1_filtered = $a1 | Where-Object -Value 'password' -Cin -Property 'k1'
Write-Host $a1_filtered
```

Please help me out on this.

Thanks

Comment: `Where-Object` doesn't work like that when you use the property syntax, the property value itself _has_ to be the left-hand side operand. You need `Where-Object { 'password' -cin $_.k1 }` if you want to invert the comparison operation.

Comment: It the official documentation of Microsoft and example is given as `Get-Process | where -Value "svchost" -CIn ProcessName`

Comment: I'm afraid that's a poor (and misleading) example, it only works because the `ProcessName` property on the input objects are single-valued. `Where ProcessName -cin svchost` therefore happens to be functionally equivalent to `Where ProcessName -eq svchost`.

Comment: You can see it works with single-valued properties like this: `@([pscustomobject]@{ k1 = 'password' }) |Where-Object k1 -cin 'password'`